# How to give access for Firebase Crashlytics only to other member?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to add member into my Firebase project who can only see Firebase Chrashlytics data.
No other information should be visible to that member.

Right now, I have added member with role **"Firebase Crashlytics Admin"**, but crash statistics does not show in that member's Firebase console. It show error as displayed in below image.

[image: Firebase Crashlytics Error]

**Note:** When I change that member's role as **"Firebase Quality Viewer"** then it show Firebase Crashlytics data on console. But it also give access to Analytics data which I don't want to give that member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following roles to get only Crashlytics viewership access in Firebase:

```
cloudnotifications.activities.list
firebase.billingPlans.get
firebase.clients.get
firebase.links.list
firebase.projects.get
firebasecrash.reports.get
firebasecrashlytics.config.get
firebasecrashlytics.data.get
firebasecrashlytics.issues.get
firebasecrashlytics.issues.list
firebasecrashlytics.sessions.get
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created custom role based on "Firebase Crashlytics Admin" and added an extra permission "firebasecrash.reports.get" to it. But still it doesn't show crash reports. Anything else I am missing?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I'll edit my comment to reflect the permissions I used to get only Crashlytics access to work.

Comment: Working now, `firebase.links.list` was missing. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is for all project in firebase. How can we add the custom role for only one project? (project based)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings -- Users and Permissions -- Assign Firebase Role -- Quality